# How to send custom header on connect for stomp using activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to set a durable subscription for my stomp client using activemq.
So far I have worked out to add activemq.subscriptionName for sending the SUBSCRIBE frame:

```
HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String,String>();
header.put("activemq.subscriptionName","unique-string-for-feed");
connection.subscribe("/topic/location", Stomp.Headers.Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT, header);
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with the CONNECT frame as there is no method that accepts a hashmap. Do I just set the client id using the client parameter from StompConnection.class?

```
public void connect(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password, java.lang.String client)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a durable subscription you need to set a client Id on the STOMP frame and use that same Id every time you connect.  Then you need to set the durable subscription name on your subscribe as you have already worked out.

See the ActiveMQ Stomp [Documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html).

You can find some good Stomp examples in the ActiveMQ Stomp unit tests as well, see testDurableUnsub in the [StompTest.java](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/trunk/activemq-stomp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/StompTest.java)

Comment: I see it, line 1502 correct? Thank you so much for the link :) I thought we could only use the methods provided in activemq